# Standard Object and their fields API for look up based on Client Name

Tags: apex, api, standard-objects, web

hello I want to create a page on our customer portal for our IT technicians to look up Account number based on the client Name. I figured out that I need to create an APEX class with an SOQL statement. I'm finding it a bit difficult to find the API for the Standard Client Object as i'ts not in the search bar like the Opportunity Object. Does any one know where I can find THE API for it. Any tips on How I would go about making this page will be usefull as well. Thanks 
[image: So far]

This is what I've done so far, mind you that I've just started with Salesforce so It's pretty basic.

Comment: You should write SELECT id FROM Clients__c not  SELECT id FROM Client. There is no Standard object named Client. There may be situation that the Account is renamed to Client.

Comment: Oh I thought maybe because if you want to select something from Opportunities you say Opportunity. Is there a way to get the API or names of those fields in Clients ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll want to check your Setup screen. Usually, you'll find that someone went in and renamed Account to Client (Setup / Quick Search "Rename" / Rename Tabs and Labels).

In that case, the object is Account, and the SOAP API Developer's Guide includes a reference to all standard objects and fields. You can see Setup / Customize / Accounts / Fields for a list of fields with their API names.

Otherwise, you'll find your clients in Setup / Create / Custom Objects, so go there, find Client, and click on the label (not edit) to see the API name for the object and its fields.

Comment: I've found all the fields and managed to make an soql statement thanks to you. Never knew about the SOAP API developer guide, Thanks